# FQL is not (!=) does not work anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

about 30 minutes ago this FQuery was working:
`SELECT pid, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id != '10150230120607577'`

However, not it says I have to use an indexable field in the WHERE condition. The documentation says object_id is indexable and besides that the query with an `=`-operator works fine, but `!=`-operator is failing.

Anyone else is having this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May or may not work, but try `<>` instead of `!=`?

**Edit:**

True answer seems to be related to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037333/fql-is-not-does-not-work-anymore/8037384?noredirect=1#comment12351948_8037384).

Comment: Can you try `object_id NOT IN (10150230120607577)`? Maybe FQL don't want you to use `''` in integer columns since you then pass them as a string?

Comment: problem found (back then), had something to do with a non existing field.. must have messed up somewhere :)

Comment: what is the exact solution??

Answer (score 1):

Try
    SELECT pid, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE NOT (object_id = 10150230120607577)

You'll still get an error, because this is not indexable, but this is how you can do negation anyway.

Comment: ++++ for this lifesaver answer, using `NOT`. This way I can actually have a NOT IN by just doing `AND NOT(actor_id IN(a,b,c))`